# JSON: Get list of JSON Objects

Tags: java, json

In java how can I pull out the JSON objects enclosed in the "{}"?

I have tried:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jstring);
obj.getJSONArray("fileName");
```

But it only return the first object. How do I get a list with both objects?

JSON:

```
[
{
    "fileName": [
        "file1"
    ],
    "date": [
        "8/25/2015 0:00"
    ],
    "time": [
        "7/16/2009 16:51"
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "version_": 1
},
{
    "fileName": [
        "file1"
    ],
    "date": [
        "8/25/2015 0:00"
    ],
    "time": [
        "7/16/2009 16:51"
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "version_": 1
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root JSON is an Array, so first create a `JSONArray` from your `String`.

Do this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jstring);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) { // Walk through the Array.
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray arr2 = obj.getJSONArray("fileName");
    // Do whatever.
}
```

For more info, please refer to the docs on [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: This is incorrect. You can not convert JSONObject to JSONArray. First line needs to be corrected.

Comment: Ops. My bad! Done, now it's corrected ;) Thanks for pointing it out. I was typing too fast and forgot to change that from my ctrl + V haha

Answer (score -1):

You have to directly construct JSONArray from JSON string in this case.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jstring);
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jstring);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.